# sql order by inside a subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(dtLu.sLu) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, dtLu.sLu) ELSE 9999999 END asc, dtLu.sLu) as row, 
dtLu.*, dtLuDerived.cCll, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCll, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllIn, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllOut FROM dtLu
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT pLu, COUNT(pLu) AS cCll
    FROM dtCll
    GROUP BY pLu) 
    AS dtLuDerived ON dtLu.pLu = dtLuDerived.pLu
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT dtCll.pLu, SUM(cMtrCll) AS cMtrCll, SUM(cMtrCllIn) AS cMtrCllIn, SUM(cMtrCllOut) AS cMtrCllOut
    FROM dtMtrCll
    INNER JOIN dtCll on dtCll.pCll = dtMtrCll.pCll
    WHERE dtCll.pWhr IN (SELECT DISTINCT pWhr FROM dtUserWhr WHERE pUser = 5)
    GROUP BY dtCll.pLu) 
    AS dtMtrDerived ON dtLu.pLu = dtMtrDerived.pLu
INNER JOIN dtLct on dtLct.pLct = dtLu.pLct
WHERE dtLu.pLu > 0 AND dtLct.pLctAsl IN (select pAsl from dtAsl where pAslUnt = 1)
-- this is the ORDER I need
ORDER BY dtLu.pLct DESC
) a 
WHERE a.row > 0 and a.row <= 17
```

but if I use the order `ORDER BY dtLu.pLct DESC` it gives me error...

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

I searched, found various samples, but my subquery is different, 'cause is needed to retrieve only 17 rows per page *(next page will have the last line like this: `WHERE a.row > 17 and a.row <=35`)*

how can I select the top 17 rows but with an order inside?

thanks

Comment: `it gives me error...` - which is... ?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do - you can use `TOP` inside the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put the order in your inner query which doesn't work. Move the order by to the main query. Also, you should list your columns instead of using *. You could probably improved this query a bit with fewer subselects but that is outside the scope of your question.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(dtLu.sLu) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, dtLu.sLu) ELSE 9999999 END asc, dtLu.sLu) as row, 
dtLu.* --you should list the columns out here
, dtLuDerived.cCll, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCll, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllIn, dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllOut FROM dtLu
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT pLu, COUNT(pLu) AS cCll
    FROM dtCll
    GROUP BY pLu) 
    AS dtLuDerived ON dtLu.pLu = dtLuDerived.pLu
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT dtCll.pLu, SUM(cMtrCll) AS cMtrCll, SUM(cMtrCllIn) AS cMtrCllIn, SUM(cMtrCllOut) AS cMtrCllOut
    FROM dtMtrCll
    INNER JOIN dtCll on dtCll.pCll = dtMtrCll.pCll
    WHERE dtCll.pWhr IN (SELECT DISTINCT pWhr FROM dtUserWhr WHERE pUser = 5)
    GROUP BY dtCll.pLu) 
    AS dtMtrDerived ON dtLu.pLu = dtMtrDerived.pLu
INNER JOIN dtLct on dtLct.pLct = dtLu.pLct
WHERE dtLu.pLu > 0 AND dtLct.pLctAsl IN (select pAsl from dtAsl where pAslUnt = 1)
-- this is the ORDER I need
--ORDER BY dtLu.pLct DESC
) a 
WHERE a.row > 0 and a.row <= 17
order by a.pLct
```

Comment: thanks @Sean, but this doesn't work, 'cause it order the first 17 records, I wish took the first 17 records that have the order that I need

Comment: Huh? Your comment is not at all clear. You get 17 rows but you want 17 rows. What order do you want them?

Comment: I try to explain: the query without order gives me this: http://i.imgur.com/8xewPHc.png 'cause the default order is by the 'name' field. if I want order for example for the Location field (locazione) desc, the rows that I need to see are not the row present in this image, but other...

Comment: Tables have no default order. Also, you are using RowNumber to add a number to your rows. If you want a certain order you could add another ROW_NUMBER to use as your row criteria.

Comment: Or you could add a top 17 to your subquery and put the order by back in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TOP 100 Percent` in Subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT top 100 percent Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN Isnumeric(dtLu.sLu) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, dtLu.sLu) ELSE 9999999 END ASC, dtLu.sLu) AS row,
               dtLu.*,
               dtLuDerived.cCll,
               dtMtrDerived.cMtrCll,
               dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllIn,
               dtMtrDerived.cMtrCllOut
        FROM   dtLu
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pLu,
                                       Count(pLu) AS cCll
                                FROM   dtCll
                                GROUP  BY pLu) AS dtLuDerived
                            ON dtLu.pLu = dtLuDerived.pLu
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT dtCll.pLu,
                                       Sum(cMtrCll)    AS cMtrCll,
                                       Sum(cMtrCllIn)  AS cMtrCllIn,
                                       Sum(cMtrCllOut) AS cMtrCllOut
                                FROM   dtMtrCll
                                       INNER JOIN dtCll
                                               ON dtCll.pCll = dtMtrCll.pCll
                                WHERE  dtCll.pWhr IN (SELECT DISTINCT pWhr
                                                      FROM   dtUserWhr
                                                      WHERE  pUser = 5)
                                GROUP  BY dtCll.pLu) AS dtMtrDerived
                            ON dtLu.pLu = dtMtrDerived.pLu
               INNER JOIN dtLct
                       ON dtLct.pLct = dtLu.pLct
        WHERE  dtLu.pLu > 0
               AND dtLct.pLctAsl IN (SELECT pAsl
                                     FROM   dtAsl
                                     WHERE  pAslUnt = 1)
        -- this is the ORDER I need
        ORDER  BY dtLu.pLct DESC) a
WHERE  a.row > 0
       AND a.row <= 17
```